# How can only the checked values be posted in a table?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

I only want to post or retrieve the checked values if they have been posted.
My code is working correctly. But I am not getting checked values. For example, if example and example 3 are marked, I get an incorrect result as in the image. Because unchecked values are also posted.
I tried similar solutions. However none of them work for me.
Image: [Link](https://i.ibb.co/zm6gVWG/imag2341243.png) 
My code is below:

```
<?php 
        $item_id    = array(0 => 5, 1=>2, 2=>4);
        $product_id = array(0 => 1421, 1=>1242, 2=>1243);
        $item_qty   = array(0 => 8, 1=>4, 2=>12);
        
        $all_data  = array(
            0 => array(
            'name'           => 'example',
        ),
            1 => array(
                'name'          => 'example-2'
        ),
        2 => array(
                'name'          => 'example-3'
        )
        );

    $counter = 0;
    ?>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <th></th>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach($all_data as $data):?>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <input type="hidden" name="item_id[]" value="<?php  echo ( $item_id[$counter] ); ?>">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="product_id[]" value="<?php echo ( $product_id[$counter] ); ?>">
                </th>
                <td><?php echo $data['name']; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <select name="item_qty[]" id="item_qty[]">
                        <?php
                        for ( $i = 1; $i <= $item_qty[$counter]; $i++ ) {
                            echo '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $i . '</option>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>        
                <?php 
                $counter++;
                endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

<?php 
if ( !isset( $_POST['submit'] ) && !isset( $_POST['product_id'] )  ) {
    return;
}   
$data = array();
foreach ( $_POST['product_id'] as $key => $product_id ) {
    $data [] = [
        'product_id'=>  $product_id,
        'item_qty'  =>  !empty( $_POST['item_qty'][$key] ) ? $_POST['item_qty'][$key] : 0,
        'item_id'   =>  !empty( $_POST['item_id'][$key] ) ? $_POST['item_id'][$key] : 0,
    ];
}
echo '<pre>'; print_r($data); echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: Checkboxes only send a value, if they have been checked. This is different from other field types such as text or hidden, which will _always_ send a value - even if that value is just an empty string. So you can not mix these field types when using `name="foo[]"` syntax - the indexes of your checkboxes, and the other field types, will start to diverge.

Comment: You can avoid such problems, by explicitly _specifying_ the index to use upfront - `name="checkbox[0]"`, `name="checkbox[1]"`, etc. Then you will still have "holes" in the index of your checkbox POST parameter - but you can simply foreach over the array, and then use the key you get while doing that, to access the corresponding text/hidden fields you named with the same pattern.

Comment: ^ or use the actual `$product_id` as index rather than using `$counter`

Comment: Is this a JS problem, or a PHP problem? Why did you tag your question with Javascript and jQuery, but haven't shared any such code?

Comment: This is also a solvable problem with javascript.  @Nico

Comment: @CBroe Thank you. However, I couldn't understand how to distinguish which is which on the backend side of this dynamic build.

Comment: If this is solvable using Javascript, please share your attempts

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you name the fields like I suggested, then your problem should already be solved. `foreach ( $_POST['product_id']` will only loop over the product IDs that were actually checked in the frontend, and pick the corresponding data out of the other two arrays via the $key.

Comment: @CBroe I got it wrong in the beginning. I'm sorry. You're right.

Answer (score 0):

When the Button is clicked, all the CheckBoxes inside the HTML Table will be referenced and then the Row (Cell) values of selected (checked) CheckBoxes will be extracted and displayed using JavaScript Alert Message Box.

**HTML Markup**
The following HTML Markup consists of an HTML Table and a Button.

```
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="Table1" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tr>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th style="width:80px">Customer Id</th>
        <th style="width:120px">Name</th>
        <th style="width:120px">Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>j</td>
        <td>c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>w</td>
        <td>c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>r</td>
        <td>f</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
<input id = "btnGet" type="button" value="Get Selected" />
```

Inside the jQuery document ready event handler, the Button has been assigned a jQuery Click event handler.
When the Button is clicked, a jQuery each loop is executed over all the selected (checked) CheckBoxes inside the HTML Table and the values of Cells of the Row are extracted and displayed using JavaScript Alert Message Box.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        //Assign Click event to Button.
        $("#btnGet").click(function () {
            var message = "Id Name                  Country\n";
 
            //Loop through all checked CheckBoxes in GridView.
            $("#Table1 input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function () {
                var row = $(this).closest("tr")[0];
                message += row.cells[1].innerHTML;
                message += "   " + row.cells[2].innerHTML;
                message += "   " + row.cells[3].innerHTML;
                message += "\n";
            });
 
            //Display selected Row data in Alert Box.
            alert(message);
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

**in PHP**

While looping on **$languages_arr** Array check **$language** value exists in **$checked_arr** Array. If exists then assign "checked" to **$checked** and use in the checkbox creation.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>

  <?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    if(!empty($_POST['lang'])) {

      $lang = implode(",",$_POST['lang']);

      // Insert and Update record
      $checkEntries = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM languages");
      if(mysqli_num_rows($checkEntries) == 0){
        mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO languages(language) VALUES('".$lang."')");
      }else{
        mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE languages SET language='".$lang."' ");
      }
 
    }

  }
  ?>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form method="post" action="">
    <span>Select languages</span><br/>
    <?php

    $checked_arr = array();

    // Fetch checked values
    $fetchLang = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM languages");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($fetchLang) > 0){
      $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetchLang);
      $checked_arr = explode(",",$result['language']);
    }

    // Create checkboxes
    $languages_arr = array("PHP","JavaScript","jQuery","AngularJS");
    foreach($languages_arr as $language){

      $checked = "";
      if(in_array($language,$checked_arr)){
        $checked = "checked";
      }
      echo '<input type="checkbox" name="lang[]" value="'.$language.'" '.$checked.' > '.$language.' <br/>';
    }
    ?>
 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
  </form>

  </body>
</html>
```